# google Map Tiles API tile как загруженная карта оффлайн?

Tags: google-maps-api

как можно загрузить карту google maps какой либо области\города
допустим на sdcard,
для отображения этой карты оффлайн в своём android приложении
через google maps sdk (googleMap)

подходит ли для этого Map Tiles API tile?
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/tile?hl=ru

и как тогда получить тогда нужные tile определенной области\города?
чтобы их использовать в коде:

```
// Создание TileOverlayOptions и настройка директории, содержащей плитки для оффлайн-карты
TileOverlayOptions options = new TileOverlayOptions()
    .tileProvider(new FileTileProvider(new File("/путь/к/директории/с/плитками")))
    .zIndex(0);

// Добавление TileOverlay на карту
TileOverlay tileOverlay = googleMap.addTileOverlay(options);
```

и возможно ли это через tile?